# How to merge subform array into single array in Zend Framework1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am using Zend Framework1.11. In my Zend Form I have two zend sub form, I have added these two sub form using addSubForm function.

Now when I call this zend form in controller then isValid function is not working. I have called it as follow..

```
public function registeredAction(){
    $form = new Application_Form_RegisteredForm();
    $form->setAction('registered');
    $formData = $this->_request->getPost();

    if($form->isValid($formData)){
       // save into database using model class.
    } else {
      $form->populate($formData); 
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

In following code isValid is not working, while I print_r the $fotmData requested array, it print array like:-

```
   Array(
          [personal] => Array
          (
             [firstname] => 'Example',
             [lastname]  => 'Solution' 
          )
         [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 8388608
         [address] => Array
         (
            [country] => 'IND',
            [state] => 'RAJ'
         )
   );
```

I have also used the setData() function but it is not working, it's give exceptional error "Message: Method setData does not exist", I have used php array_merge function but return array is not working with isValid().

Can anyone help me to solve this problem. so I can easily store form data into database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at array_merge

http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-merge.php

```
$newFormData=array_merge($formData["personal"],$formData["address"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create new base form with new method getSubFormsValues(), i.e.:

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    public function getSubFormsValues()
    {
        $values = array();

        foreach ($this->getSubForms() as $form) {
            $name = $form->getName();
            $value = $form->getValues(); 

            $values = array_merge($value[$name], $values);    
        }

        return $values;
    }
}

When you can call $my_form_obj->getSubFormValues() in your code.
```